# Django run durable transaction via gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, atomic

I have a django (3.2v) application with an atomic based transaction which uses durable option

```
@transaction.atomic(durable=True)
def get_account():
    ...
```

I'm able of running my project via `python manage.py runserver` and everything works fine. But when I run my project via `gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 myapp.wsgi:application` I get the following error:

> TypeError: atomic() got an unexpected keyword argument 'durable'

after removing `durable=True` param from atomic decorator like the code below, everything works like a charm.

```
@transaction.atomic
def get_account():
    ...
```

why this happens? how can I make this work?